# How to add target to link within field instructions?

Tags: field, markdown, field-instructions

I don't see anything in the documentation about how flexible the instructions fields are, as they use Markdown syntax. It's not clear how to add a target to a link, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft uses Github Flavored Markdown and I don't believe targets are supported in links: https://github.github.com/gfm/#links

Honestly, not sure that I've seen any Markdown flavors that actually support that.